# How to take a subset of an object using an interface?

Tags: oop, typescript, interface, typescript2.0, mass-assignment

Suppose I have this class and interface

```
class User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}

interface IUser {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

And then I get this json object from somewhere

```
const data = {
    name: "John",
    age: 25,
    isAdmin: true
}
```

I want to subset `data` using `IUser` and remove the `isAdmin` property like this

```
let user = subset<IUser>(data);
// user is now { name: "John", age: 25 }
// can safely insert user in the db
```

My question is how do I implement that function in TypeScript?

```
function subset<T>(obj: object) {
    // keep all properties of obj that are in T
    // keep, all optional properties in T
    // remove any properties out of T
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do that which is better than:

```
function subset(obj: IUser) {
    return {
        name: obj.name,
        age: obj.age
    }
}
```

The typescript interfaces don't exist at runtime (which is when `subset` is invoked) so you cannot use the `IUser` interface to know which properties are needed and which aren't.

You can use a class which does "survive" the compilation process **but**:

```
class IUser {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var IUser = (function () {
    function IUser() {
    }
    return IUser;
}());
```

As you can see, the properties aren't part of the compiled output, as the class members are only added to the instance and not to the class, so even a class won't help you.

You can use decorator and metadata ([more on that here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata)) but that sounds like an overkill for your scenario.

Another option for a more generic `subset` function is:

```
function subset<T>(obj: T, ...keys: (keyof T)[]) {
    const result = {} as T;

    keys.forEach(key => result[key] = obj[key]);
    return result;
}
let user1 = subset(data, "name", "age");
let user2 = subset(data, "name", "ag"); // error: Argument of type '"ag"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age" | "isAdmin"'
```