# TypeScript: How to merge an object from another interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface TxInterface {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
    field3: number;
}

interface RxInterface {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
    field3: number;
    field4: string;
    field5: string;
}
```

When I receive an object from server, it is typed with RxInterface. In my App, I continue to use this object when I update values for instance.

When I would like to update object in server, I shall send "TxInterface", that contains some fields of "RxInterface".

So, how can I easily to merge my object from RxInterface to TxInterface before send and take only the fields of TxInterface?

Comment: Would you clarify the last part? If you need to send only TxInterface fields to the server then it won't be a merge, more like a reduce of the larger object to the smaller one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a subset of an object using an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028324/how-to-take-a-subset-of-an-object-using-an-interface)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an object of an interface to its base interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682572/convert-an-object-of-an-interface-to-its-base-interface)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript - extract interface members only - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839597/typescript-extract-interface-members-only-possible)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this merely with the interface definitions, since such definitions are part of the type system which is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) by runtime.  If you need something done at runtime, you need to write code which does it at runtime.  In this case, here's a generic function which extracts just the properties of an object matching a list of keys:

```
function extract<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T,
    keys: K[]
): Pick<T, K> {
    const ret = {} as Pick<T, K>;
    keys.forEach(k => ret[k] = obj[k])
    return ret;
}
```

And for your specific use case, you can make a conversion function whose types involve `RxInterface` and `TxInterface`, but which specifies the particular keys you care about as values and not types:

```
const rxToTx = (rx: RxInterface): TxInterface => // type annotation here
    extract(rx, ["field1", "field2", "field3"]); // explicit key values here
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
const rx: RxInterface = {
    field1: "yes",
    field2: "yep",
    field3: 100,
    field4: "no",
    field5: "nope"
}

const tx = rxToTx(rx);

console.log(tx);
// {field1: "yes", field2: "yep", field3: 100}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Your solution works but warnings are raised and I can't find a solution. The head warning is "Argument type [string , string , string] is not assignable to parameter type keyof T[] ". I works with PhpStorm.

Comment: Uh, I can't reproduce your issue.  If you are using TS3.4+ you can try `["field1", "field2", "field3"] as const`, but I think it should work as stated.  Do you have a way of producing a [mcve] which demonstrates your problem?  If I can't reproduce it it's hard to give advice.

Comment: I use TS3.2 in Angular 7 app. Minimal example can be "Create Angular 7 project" then "Add the snippets in app.component.ts"

Comment: I don't have PhpStorm, so unless your example can be reproduced via a link to some web IDE like [this](https://typescript-play.js.org/) or [this](https://repl.it/languages/typescript), I don't think I can be of much help here.  And if you suspect that your issue is specific to PhpStorm, you should add that tag to your question... (maybe a new question, since I doubt you'll get much eyes on this one if you just edit it)

Answer (score 0):

All right. It is a good starting point to introduce binary operations also known as "reductions".

Consider generic function signature: `T -> T -> T`. What it does is takes two parameters of the same type `T` and somehow "collapses" them into a single resulting instance of the same type `T`. As a trivial example, take `+` on `number`s or concatenation on the `string`s.

It turns out that such a binary operation is unbelievably common across various branches of math and founded on a much more reliable reasons then just a programming convenience. For example, a "[semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup)" is essentially the same binary operation with few additional properties, I won't explain here.

So, don't ignore it. Rather design you code in such a way that you can leverage binary operations of the abovementioned (generic) signature. The question is: how? Mapping! Have you ever heard something about "map/reduce" approach? That's exactly what you are about to implement: firstly map a non-reducible instance into a reducible one and then apply one of reductions you have in order to compute final result.

P.S. In your case mapping since to be trivial: just specify explicitly generic params, since a wider interface is also satisfies narrower interface.